# Trying to cancel a timer

Tags: timer, lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to cancel a timer but it doesn't get canceled when it should, and each time a touch event occurs, a new timer gets added:

```
local fireTimer

local function onTouch( event )

  if( event.phase == "began") then
    fireTimer = timer.performWithDelay( 3000, fire, 0 ) <-- works fine

  elseif( event.phase == "ended" ) then
    timer.cancel( fireTimer ) <-- doesn't work, it keeps going, "pause" doesn't work either

  end
end

player:addEventListener( "touch", onTouch )
```

Comment: have you checked the docs?  https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/timer/cancel.html

Comment: Also here https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/timer/source.html

Comment: So basically you will want to reference the `event` param's properties to determine if an event is active.

Answer (score 1):

It is because your touch event is indeed "ended" before fire starts and therefore wont cancel that function:

See this example where it works when the delay is only 1 instead of your 3000.

```
local player = display.newRect( 0, 0, 150, 50 )

local function fire( )
    print("touched")
end

local function fireTimer2( )
    print("Ended touched")
end

local function onTouch( event )

  if( event.phase == "began") then
    fireTimer = timer.performWithDelay( 1, fire, 0 )

  elseif( event.phase == "ended" ) then
    timer.cancel( fireTimer ) 
    print("Ended touched")
  end
end

player:addEventListener( "touch", onTouch )
```